# How to correctly parallelize multiple JSON file aggregation in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large set of json_list files on S3 with some logs that I would like to aggregate (basically just count number of requests by path, location etc.) I've been doing the following, but judging by the logs, I'm not sure it's actually parallelized.. first it takes about 3 minutes to download the individual S3 files one by one, and then the rest still seems split to 1000 executions.. I thought Spark would break this down into a map-reduce kind of approach itself but maybe I totally misunderstood what it does and what it doesn't do. Could someone provide a hint please.

```
df = (
    spark.read
    .json(test_paths, schema=schema)
    .filter(col('method') == 'GET')
    .filter((col('status_code') == 200) | (col('status_code') == 206))
    .withColumn('date', from_unixtime('timestamp').cast(DateType()))
    .groupBy('path', 'client_country_code', 'date', 'file_size')
    .count()
)
```

Here's the driver log for 1000 urls:

```
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO InMemoryFileIndex: Listing leaf files and directories in parallel under 1000 paths. The first several paths are: s3n://bucket../10004.json_lines.gz.
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: json at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 49 (json at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) with 1000 output partitions
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 75 (json at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 75 (MapPartitionsRDD[206] at json at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0), which has no missing parents
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_77 stored as values in memory (estimated size 84.3 KiB, free 2.2 GiB)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_77_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 29.9 KiB, free 2.2 GiB)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_77_piece0 in memory on e05e979b7108:34999 (size: 29.9 KiB, free: 2.2 GiB)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 77 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1223
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1000 missing tasks from ResultStage 75 (MapPartitionsRDD[206] at json at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 75.0 with 1000 tasks
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33224, e05e979b7108, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7473 bytes)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33225, e05e979b7108, executor driver, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7473 bytes)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33226, e05e979b7108, executor driver, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7474 bytes)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33227, e05e979b7108, executor driver, partition 3, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7475 bytes)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33228, e05e979b7108, executor driver, partition 4, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7476 bytes)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33229, e05e979b7108, executor driver, partition 5, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7477 bytes)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 6.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33230, e05e979b7108, executor driver, partition 6, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7477 bytes)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33231, e05e979b7108, executor driver, partition 7, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7477 bytes)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33224)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33225)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33226)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO Executor: Running task 5.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33229)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33227)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO Executor: Running task 7.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33231)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO Executor: Running task 6.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33230)
20/11/15 19:15:23 INFO Executor: Running task 4.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33228)
20/11/15 19:15:24 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33225). 2025 bytes result sent to driver
20/11/15 19:15:24 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33224). 2025 bytes result sent to driver
20/11/15 19:15:24 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 8.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33232, e05e979b7108, executor driver, partition 8, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7477 bytes)
20/11/15 19:15:24 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33225) in 567 ms on e05e979b7108 (executor driver) (1/1000)
20/11/15 19:15:24 INFO Executor: Running task 8.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33232)
20/11/15 19:15:24 INFO Executor: Finished task 6.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33230). 2033 bytes result sent to driver
20/11/15 19:15:24 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 9.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33233, e05e979b7108, executor driver, partition 9, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7477 bytes)
20/11/15 19:15:24 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 10.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33234, e05e979b7108, executor driver, partition 10, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7477 bytes)
20/11/15 19:15:24 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33224) in 570 ms on e05e979b7108 (executor driver) (2/1000)
20/11/15 19:15:24 INFO Executor: Running task 9.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33233)
20/11/15 19:15:24 INFO Executor: Running task 10.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33234)
20/11/15 19:15:24 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 6.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 33230) in 571 ms on e05e979b7108 (executor driver) (3/1000)
....
20/11/15 19:15:43 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 998.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 34222) in 158 ms on e05e979b7108 (executor driver) (999/1000)
20/11/15 19:15:43 INFO Executor: Finished task 999.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 34223). 2033 bytes result sent to driver
20/11/15 19:15:43 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 999.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 34223) in 175 ms on e05e979b7108 (executor driver) (1000/1000)
20/11/15 19:15:43 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 75.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
20/11/15 19:15:43 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 75 (json at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) finished in 19.850 s
20/11/15 19:15:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 49 is finished. Cancelling potential speculative or zombie tasks for this job
20/11/15 19:15:43 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 75: Stage finished
20/11/15 19:15:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 49 finished: json at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0, took 19.890458 s
20/11/15 19:15:43 INFO InMemoryFileIndex: It took 19936 ms to list leaf files for 1000 paths.
```

Comment: Can you include the driver console with the stages for this execution?

Comment: sure thing  - added to op

Comment: You have 1000 tasks that correspond to the partitions which are used to process the dataframe. In the web console  you have to see the tasks x executor, there you see how Spark paralellizes

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of setup overhead, especially with many small files. JSON is also a very inefficient storage format as the whole file will be needed to be read every time. Ideally each file should be 64+MB to give the spark workers enough data to process efficiently.

Have you considered making step 1 of your workflow just reading in the JSON files and then saving in a columnar format like Parquet to a smaller number of files.?